# TestFlight: My build is immediately available to internal testers. Why might this be?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I have a React Native app on TestFlight. In the past I've always had to wait about 12 hours for the TestFlight build to be approved, and then its status shows as `Testing` or `Approved`. With the app I'm working on now, its status is just `Ready To Submit` and it was available for Internal Testers immediately. Does anyone know what the difference between these two scenarios is? The reason I'm wondering is that the build available to internal testers now is behaving differently than I expected it too, and in order to troubleshoot this I want to know if this immediately-available `Ready To Submit` type of build is expected to behave differently than other builds.

Answer (score 3):

Builds are always available for internals testers immediately after you upload them (given that you have added internal testers for that particular version).

Apple’s beta review only applies for externals testers. If you have external testers added to the build, they need to wait for the review to complete successfully before they can download the build in TestFlight. Internals testers for the same build will get it right away without waiting for the review.